# Install cursors using VB.NET app?

Tags: vb.net, cursor, installation

Is it possible to create a VB.NET application that can install cursors? I have already been using .inf files to install them, but I want more flexibility. Is this possible?

Please note I do not want to use them in the application, but install them so they work in Windows all around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Code will help you in making this program:

`CurrentUser` - Stores information about user preferences (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`)

`LocalMachine` - Stores configuration information for the local machine (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`)

`ClassesRoot` - Stores information about types (and classes) and their properties (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`).

`Users` - Stores information about the default user configuration (`HKEY_USERS`).

Comment: Thank you very much! The only thing I want to add is I also had to run `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL main.cpl @0,1` to open the mouse settings window so the changes actually apply.

Comment: @Nicolas Gnyra you can install directlly an installer file (.inf) of a cursor using only Rundll32, and set it as default.

Comment: Yes, I know, it's just I wanted more customizability.